# Can't acces prop inside method

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a single file component in Vue which takes an object as a prop called `data`. I want to access this prop inside a custom function that I'm creating. Here's my code

```
<script>
import { db } from "../main";

export default {
  name: "UserDetail",
  props: ["data"],
  methods: {
    verifyUserProfile: () => {
      console.log(this.data);
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(this.data.uid)
        .update({
          idProofVerified: true
        })
     }
  }
    };
</script>
```

When I use the data prop in template it works just fine but in the function its giving me `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: I'm using this component inside View like so:

```
  <div>
    <UserDetail :data="users[selected]" />
  </div>
```

Where users is an array of users objects.

Comment: what data did you pass here? can you show it too?

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: The problem is your use of arrow functions and how they bind `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `() => {}` so `this` points to the global context. Replace it with `verifyUserProfile: function () { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely calling the method before the props have arrived at the component, typically the `props` come in only after the lifecycle methods and therefore if you call a function which tries to access them there it will be undefined.
A solution to this would be to place a watcher on the props and then trigger the function once the props have received a value.
Like so:

```
watch: {
    data: {
       immediate: true, 
       handler(val){
         if (val){
             this.verifyUserProfile()
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm calling the function on a button click. So I dont think thats the issue.

Comment: Why are you using the method as a property, the normal way to do it would be 
`verifyUserProfile(){ .... }`, try that maybe

Comment: You know what, I think you might be clashing with vue's internal `data` try renaming your prop to lterally anything else and see if that helps ("myData")